# Speech recognition engine in Dutch

Tags: speech-recognition

I am currently searching for a speech engine for Dutch. My engine needs to detect keywords only, like: 'stand up', 'say hello', 'walk forward', etc.

I have looked up CMU Sphinx4, Dragon Nuance(not free), Kaldi, Julius. But I have no idea which one to choose.

Hope you guys can help me.